# Doctrine 2 association mapping errors

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities:

```
Brs\UserBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: user
repositoryClass: Brs\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    username:
        type: string
        length: 50
    fname:
        type: string
        length: 30
    lname:
        type: string
        length: 30
    email:
        type: string
        length: 75
    mobile:
        type: string
        length: 20
    active:
        type: boolean
    mentor:
        type: boolean
    roll:
        type: string
        length: 10
    profitPercentage:
        type: string
        length: 10
    initialized:
        type: datetime
    password:
        type: string
        length: 255
oneToMany:
    requests:
        targetEntity: Brs\FundingBundle\Entity\Request
        mappedBy: requests
```

and:

```
Brs\FundingBundle\Entity\Request:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: Brs\FundingBundle\Entity\RequestRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    amount:
        type: integer
    status:
        type: integer
    datetime:
        type: datetime
    note:
        type: string
        length: 255
    approval:
        type: boolean
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: Brs\UserBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: user
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

in Brs\FundingBundle\Entity\Request:

I have the property declared:

```
private $user;
```

and in Brs\FundingBundle\Entity\User:

I have the property declared:

```
private $requests;
```

When I run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get the following result:

```
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "3" queries were executed
```

Which seems fine, This creates the requests table and adds the user_id foreign key to it which is what I want.

However I have mulled over the documentation over at [Doctrine 2 association mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) and I cannot seem to understand confidently the inverse, owning and mappedBy logic.

If someone could explain this with regards to my example above thoroughly It would be greatly appreciated.

So in this instance a user **has many** requests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations).

Probably using annotations will be more convenient.